# Oracle PL/SQL debugging permission implications

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql

In order to be able to debug a PL/SQL code on Oracle database one must have a DEBUG permission which is not granted by default (GRANT DEBUG CONNECT SESSION TO username).

Now I develop some PL/SQL procedures without explicit debugging (tracing errors with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()) since I don't have DEBUG permission at the moment. DWH DBA refused to grant me this permission without giving the reason. Before talking with him, I'd like to know what could be the reason that he refused to grant me this permission.

What are the (security or performance) implications of having DEBUG permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBAs are trained, or taught over time, to generally deny all requests for granting privileges to users.

Why? Because it generally leads to exposing the database, and their #1 job is to secure the database.

So, when asking for a privilege, you need to make a business case for it. In general, one would think you would only be debugging your code in a DEVELOPMENT instance, not a production one. If you're asking for this priv in PRODUCTION, he or she might be telling you don't be debugging in PRODUCTION!

As for overhead or the 'cost' of your privilege - compiling PL/SQL for debug does add overhead. In other words, it will cost more to execute your program. The database is collecting more information than it normally does. You don't want your pl/sql to have this overhead in a production environment - it can ONLY slow it down.

In order to win your case, assuming you're talking about a development instance - I'd argue that having DBMS_OUTPUT in your code also poses a problem. You have to remember to turn it off before putting into production, AND it's inefficient. So sell the benefit to the DBA, less DBMS_OUTPUT code in production to worry about.

Comment: You said that "compiling PL/SQL for debug does add overhead". Ok, that's during debugging phase but when debugging is finished and package is complete and correctly compiled, there's no overhead. In order to trace my errors with DBMS_OUTPUT and not having a debugging capability I have to run my package much more times than with debugging. That's practical overhead for me in development as fof db as well.

Comment: no, when you COMPILE FOR DEBUG - the overhead on execution remains there until you COMPILE it again - which then removes the DEBUG info

Comment: sorry, read your comment again, yeah after your 2nd compile, the overhead goes away

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "overhead or the 'cost' of your privilege ", in production environment, we want to compare the production code between prod and development  or let say after a release, we want to do code sanity checks to validate the new code is reflecting. For these reason we need access only to see the code, no debugging or execution. Is still ok to deploy the procedure with DEBUG privilege without any break.